# How to allow only the master branch to trigger builds on Jenkins using GitLab Plugin

Tags: regex, git, jenkins, gitlab, devops

I'm trying to restrict only the master branch to can trigger builds on my Jenkins Pipeline.

I already tried "Filter branches by name" and "Filter branches by regex" but nothing has worked.

Someone can help me please?

[image]

Thank you...

Comment: What's the problem ? It does trigger the build ? If yes, can you please extract some logs ?

Comment: Please see the **Note** section on the plugin page for Branch filtering - https://github.com/jenkinsci/gitlab-plugin/blob/master/README.md#branch-filtering . For pipeline jobs, please run your job manually once as instructed. Also, you have comment regex to trigger build, ensure your comment is also matching this.

Answer (score 1):

I also had same problem. And this saved me

To filter according to the payload 'ref' tag, optional filter is set in jenkins pipeline job.

[image]

Then applied optional filter on 'ref' variable, to allow only master branch

[image]

or expression could be simply

> refs/heads/master

Now my jenkins job is triggering only when there is a commit to master

---